# Oracle database installation version enforcing stricter SQL rules on group by function

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

Recently I copied an Oracle database from one machine to another.

1. **Original**: Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.3.0
2. **Copy**: Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
   For some reason the following query works on the original but not on the copy.

If a t.tdt_id is substituted in place of tdt_id in the group by the query works (as per td_tablespaces t )

Can someone explain why this is and if it has something to do with the installation. The data is the exact same in both.

```
SELECT
    tdt_name as "name", 
    tdt_contents as "Content",         
    tdt_status as "Status",         
    round(( subsize.SubSize_MB ), 2 ) as "size used",         
    round(( sum( MaxMB ) - subsize.SubSize_MB ), 2 ) as "size free" 
FROM    
    td_tablespaces t 
INNER JOIN        
    (
        SELECT 
            tdt_id,
            CASE 
                 WHEN upper( d.df_autoextend ) = 'YES' THEN  round(( sum( df_maxsize ) / 1024 ), 2 )  
                 WHEN upper( d.df_autoextend ) = 'NO' THEN round(( Sum( df_size ) / 1024 ), 2 )                 
            END as MaxMB
        FROM    
            td_datafiles d         
        GROUP BY 
            tdt_id,                 
            d.df_autoextend,                 
            df_maxsize,                 
            df_size         
    ) sub 
ON      
    t.tdt_id = sub.tdt_id 
INNER JOIN        
    (
        SELECT 
            tdt_id,                 
            sum( df_size / 1024 ) -( df_free / 1024 ) SubSize_MB,                 
        df_free      / 1024 SubSize_Free         
        FROM    
            td_datafiles df         
        GROUP BY 
            tdt_id,                 
            df_free         
    ) subsize 
ON 
    t.tdt_id = subsize.tdt_id 
WHERE 
    ins_id   = 2096 
GROUP BY 
    tdt_id,         
    tdt_name,         
    tdt_contents,        
    tdt_status,         
    subsize.SubSize_MB,         
    SubSize_Free 
ORDER BY tdt_contents
```

Comment: How does the query fail?

Comment: Oh sorry, a "column ambigously defined" error occurs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle enforces strict rules when referencing columns in a query and will raise `ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined` if a column is found on two tables and referenced without a table prefix or an alias.

Since `tdt_id` is defined both in `t` and `subsize`, you couldn't call `tdt_id` without an alias or a table name in:

- the `SELECT` clause
- the `WHERE` clause
- the `ORDER BY` clause

For some reason in some versions of 10g the error is not raised when the column is in a `GROUP BY` clause. This is inconsistent with the rest of the syntax parsing, this could lead to ambiguous results and must have been classified as a bug. This has been corrected in 11g.

Comment: Would you consider that a bug in 10g that 11g fixes? I would imagine DB administrators across the world who has this written in their queries had to fix it when upgrading

Comment: They had written ambiguous queries =) This should be caught in the tests done before upgrading (you test this sort of things I hope)! Don't undergo a major version change without running all queries on the new test version beforehand. Edit: by the way I got caught by this unexpected "bug" and I had to change a few of my queries during a migration.

Comment: No I didn't write the query, it is embedded in some.net code(another headache). It looks like Paul's answer above might explain why it is behaving the way it is. I could disect it and prove that but I don't have time to do that I'm afraid. Thanks for your input, appreciated.

Comment: I think that @Paul is right: as part of an upgrade to the CBO, Oracle corrected what was qualified as a bug (10g not raising ORA-918). MOS reference: [Bug 5368296](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/ui/km/BugDisplay.jspx?_afrLoop=769151484325553&id=5368296&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=15adnbyvcj_135) [ID 835701.1](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/ui/km/SearchDocDisplay.jspx?_afrLoop=769316595518757&type=DOCUMENT&id=835701.1&displayIndex=1&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=15adnbyvcj_180)

Comment: From reading up on that bug it seems like it was a known and accepted bug in oracle 10g but corrected in 11g explaining my issue. I don't think Paul's answer supplies the answer to this bug I came across persay, it just describes methods of improved query optimisation. What do you think. P.s. thanks for all your input on this.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is 'stricter rules', I think this is a side effect of improved query optimisation. In oracle 11, the optimizer may try to perform `group by` actions before certain joins in order to minimize the number of rows joined.

See pages 19-20 here for details http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/bi-datawarehousing/twp-upgrading-10g-to-11g-what-to-ex-133707.pdf

Comment: @@paul thanks for the link, I read the relevant section. How come the query works for the rest of the group by without a t. reference?

Comment: because `tdt_id` is the only column name that appears in more than one table